# How to convert from fraction formatted string to Decimal or Float in Java?

Tags: java, android, math

I have few string values which I am fetching from my database e.g

```
"1/4","2/3"
```

But while displaying as Android ListView contents I need to display it as `0.25`,`0.66`.

Now I don't want to split the string and then covert to individual strings to numbers and
then divide them to have result.

Does anyone know, any direct functions like `Double.valueOf` or `parseDouble` kind?

Comment: Your requirement to find a solution seems unreasonable, it does seems like the best approach to do it like that.

Comment: Yes gabriel, even i was thinking why would someone save values as 1/4 and 2/3 in database, but as far as client concern, yes they do have such values, so needed that work-around.

Comment: My comment wasn't regarding how the data was saved(having seeing some weird thing myself), but to your restriction to using a split("/") to solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, but then how will i achieve myself a result of "1/4" string to 0.25 as float or double value, using other than split?

Comment: As people said on the Answer there is no method so you should use split, thats why I dont understand you not wanting to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why you *"dont want to split the string and then covert to individual strings to numbers and then divide them to have result"*?

I am not aware of any built-in function to do that so the simplest solution:

```
double parse(String ratio) {
    if (ratio.contains("/")) {
        String[] rat = ratio.split("/");
        return Double.parseDouble(rat[0]) / Double.parseDouble(rat[1]);
    } else {
        return Double.parseDouble(ratio);
    }
}
```

It also covers the case where you have integer representation of ratio

```
parse("1/2") => 0.5
parse("3/7") => 0.42857142857142855
parse("1") => 1.0
```

Answer (score 8):

I imagine you have solved this problem in the last 2 years; however, you can use the [Apache commons fraction class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html).

It has a built in parser, so if you were to call:

```
Fraction fraction = Fraction.getFraction("1/2");
double d = fraction.doubleValue();
```

Then d should contain .5.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the fraction using `split("/")`. Then you can convert the values to `Double` and perform the division. I have no idea of Android, that's how I'd do it in Java.

Comment: Quoting OP: _"Now i dont want to split the string and then covert to individual strings to numbers and then divide them to have result."_

Answer (score 1):

In java, we don't have anything like the eval from JavaScript so you could possibly use [this](https://github.com/MarkyVasconcelos/Towel/wiki/Expression).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is anything like that. But I don't see why you wouldn't create your own function like this:

```
public static double fromStringFraction(String fraction){
    String[] fractionArray = fraction.split("/");
    try {
        if (fractionArray.length != 2){
            if (fractionArray.length == 1){
                return Double.parseDouble(fractionArray[0]);
            }
            else {
                return 0d;
            }
        }
        double b = Double.parseDouble(fractionArray[1]);
        if (b==0d){
            return 0d;
        }
        Double a = Double.parseDouble(fractionArray[0]);
        return a/b;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return 0d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey gabga, i have alredy wrote, that i know by splitting it i can achieve the result, but did not wanted to make such work around. Anyways Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
SpannableStringBuilder test = new SpannableStringBuilder();
test.append("\n");
test.append(Html.fromHtml("<sup>5</sup>/<sub>9</sub>"));
test.append("\n");
```