# Number types on Scanner

Tags: java

I made a simple program that calculates the delta based on 3 numbers from the formula. However, it has a problem with fractions and numbers after the decimal point (eg 3.33, 3/4). If I substitute it for any letter, an error appears:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException   at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)    at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)   at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)    at
>   java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)    at
>   Main.main(Main.java:11)

How can I add a patch to make the program work correctly? My code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double n1; //a
        final double n2; //b
        final double n3; //c
        Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
        System.out.print("calculation of the delta. Enter the first number (a from the formula)");
        n1 = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("give the second number (b from the formula)");
        n2 = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("give the last number (c from the formula)");
        n3 = reader.nextDouble();
        final double delta = Math.pow(n2, 2) - 4 * n1 * n3;
        final double d01 = (-n2 + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * n1);
        final double d02 = (-n2 - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * n1);
        final String dinfo = "Delta is equal: ";
        if(delta>0) {
            System.out.println(dinfo + (int)delta + " , has [two] zero places, which is equal to: " + (int)d01 + " and " + (int)d02);
        }
        else if (delta == 0) {
            System.out.println(dinfo + (int)delta + ", has exactly [one] zero place, which is equal to: " + (int)d01);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(dinfo + (int)delta + ", no zero places.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you calculating in d01 and d02?

Comment: set double as type of n1,n2,n3 first

Comment: I'm calculating zero places of the delta. I've changed that, but the error still appears.

Comment: After you change the type to double for n1, n2 and n3 also change the nextInt() method to nextDouble() .. moreover, remove the cast to int in your print statements

Comment: I've already updated that. Without changes.

Comment: what kind of input data do you want to accept? Letter or Number? could you tell more about input data example.

Comment: Numbers. Mainly fractions, decimal numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accept input numbers as decimal, you should use `float or double` type. e.g.

```
double n1;
n1 = reader.nextDouble();
```

About fractions case, you should use String type and then convert it to number type. e.g.

```
    String tmp;
    Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
    System.out.print("calculation of the delta. Enter the first number (a from the formula)");
    tmp = reader.next();
    n1 = fractionToDouble(tmp);
    tmp = reader.next();
    n2 = fractionToDouble(tmp);
....
```

Add fractionToDouble converting method. ref:[mishadoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249858/how-to-convert-from-fraction-formatted-string-to-decimal-or-float-in-java)

```
static double fractionToDouble(String ratio) {
        if (ratio.contains("/")) {
            String[] rat = ratio.split("/");
            return Double.parseDouble(rat[0]) / Double.parseDouble(rat[1]);
        } else {
            return Double.parseDouble(ratio);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Corrected for n1,n2,n3. It still doesn't work after entering the fraction or numbers after the decimal point.

Comment: did you change as nextDouble()

Comment: I see no problem in your code, could tell me your test data?

Comment: I have created an example to better explain my problem. [here](https://i.imgur.com/JNPpDWE.png)

Comment: I see. You should reference this post  [How to convert from fraction formatted string to Decimal or Float in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249858/how-to-convert-from-fraction-formatted-string-to-decimal-or-float-in-java) if you want to input  e.g. "3/3".

Comment: Could you give me some tips on how to implement this into my code? I'm not too advanced in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Change int to double first

```
 final double n1; //a
 final double n2; //b
 final double n3; //c

 n1 = reader.nextDouble();
 n2 = reader.nextDouble();
 n3 = reader.nextDouble();
```

and you need to set Locale.us to resolve this InputMismatchException. Otherwise it may take "," or other characters as a decimal delimiter. This resolve your decimal issue

```
Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: No changes. I've updated the code in the post, please take a look.

Comment: Your code is not working only for fraction ? I think others and decimal numbers give correct answers?

Comment: My code works only on integers. Fractions and decimal numbers does not work, this is the problem.