# How to split a string at a given mark

Tags: java, regex, string

So I was working on a method named "parse" of a class called "Fraction". where this method takes a string input and store it as an object.

The input looked like this: 1/3, 3/5, 5/8, 10/3 you get the idea.

I developed a simple solution to parse a String into an object. like this

```
    public static Fraction parse(String s) {
        int parsedTop = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0));
        int parsedBottom = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(2));
        Fraction i = new Fraction(parsedTop, parsedBottom);
        return i;
    }
```

But then my solution would not work with inputs that have more than 1 digit of either the numerator or the denominator. How can I fix that?

Comment: split at `/` then convert to number

Comment: Maybe [`split("/")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) will do better

Comment: only call `Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(2));` if you string has 3 characters

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249858/how-to-convert-from-fraction-formatted-string-to-decimal-or-float-in-java for inspiration, but you may want to make some of their doubles ints

Comment: Use [`s.indexOf('/')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-), followed by [`s.substring(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) (twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is assuming that the numbers are only 1 digit long. One way to fix this is to split your string on the division character '/' and parse the before and after as an integer.

Tested with `s = "12/33"`.

```
public Fraction parse(String s) {
    String[] fractionSplit = s.split("/");
    Integer parsedTop = Integer.parseInt(fractionSplit[0]);
    Integer parsedBottom = Integer.parseInt(fractionSplit[1]);
    Fraction i = new Fraction(parsedTop, parsedBottom);
    return i;
}
```